# Stack operations using Linked LIst in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I need to write a class that implements a stack using a linked list.  The twist is that it should perform the push and pop operations from the tail of the list instead of the head, without maintaining a reference to the list’s tail node.

How can I achieve this without keeping a reference to the tail node?

Comment: you can always traverse a list up to its tail. though it would be least efficient not to keep the reference to last node.

Comment: That's called a queue. And yeah, just traverse the list every time.

Comment: I think you are confused about what the head is and what the tail is

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this but it would be pretty inefficient because you have to go through the entire list every time you want to do something. There really isn't any reason why you would want to keep a reference to the head while all the operations are performed at the tail.

But here's how I would do it anyway:

```
class Entry<E> {
    E object;
    Entry<E> next;
    public Entry(E obj) {
        object = obj;
    }
}

class StackList<E> {
    Entry<E> head;
    public void push(E element) {
        if (head == null) {
            // first
            head = new Entry<E>(element);
            return;
        }
        Entry<E> node = head;
        while (node != null && node.next != null) {
            node = node.next;
        }
        // node is now the tail
        Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(element);
        node.next = newEntry;
    }
    public E pop() {
        if (head == null) {
            // empty
            return null;
        }
        Entry<E> node = head, previousNode = null;
        while (node.next != null) {
            previousNode = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        // node is now the tail
        // previousNode is the next-to-last
        if (previousNode != null) {
            previousNode.next = null;
        } else {
            // there was only one thing
            head = null;
        }
        return node.object;
    }
}
```